# Point inside a convex polygon

Tags: geometry, polygons

I'd like to know when a point is contained in a convex $n-$polygon.I find one question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19204/distances-between-points-and-polygons), but it's different from my problem.

Comment: You could generalize my answer in the post below.  If you draw a line segment from each vertex to the point in question, you'll get a set of $n$ triangles whose area should sum to the area of the polygon if the point does lie inside (which itself can be found using a triangulation & heron's formula).  This is super-duper computation heavy though so be warned. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207697/necessary-and-sufficient-conditions-for-a-point-to-lie-inside-a-tetrahedron-vec/2207723#2207723

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A_1A_2...A_n$ be our convex polygon, $A_{n+1}\equiv A_1$  and $P$ be a point in the plain of this polygon.

Now, if
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\measuredangle A_kPA_{k+1}=360^{\circ}$$
then $P$ placed inside our polygon.

If
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\measuredangle A_kPA_{k+1}\neq360^{\circ}$$
then this is not so.

Answer (score 0):

There's a rather easy way: Let's assume your point is $P_0=(x_0,y_0)$, and your polygon is given as a sequence of points $P_i=(x_i,y_i)$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$, and let's assume $P_{n+1}=P_1$. First, you determine the indices $i$ where $P_i, P_{i+1}$ lie on different sides of the horizontal line through $P_0$, i.e. $(y_i-y_0)(y_0-y_{i+1})\ge0$. There must be two such indices. Then, you determine the abscissas of the intersection of $P_iP_{i+1}$ with $y=y_0$. If $x_0$ lies between them, your point is inside the polygon, in all other cases (meaning that there aren't two intersection points, or $x_0$ isn't between them), it's outside.

Comment: Thanks so much! But, if $P_0$ is below the polygon this logic gonna fail. Because $(y_i - y_0)(y_0 - y_{i + 1}) < 0$